# Limiting results in a custom FileMaker dialect for Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc, filemaker

I'm trying to access a FileMaker 16 database using Spring JPA 2.0.9 with Hibernate 5.3.5 using [the official JDBC driver](https://support.filemaker.com/s/answerview?language=en_US&anum=12921) and [this dialect](https://github.com/johnkeates/hibernate-filemaker-dialect) for Hibernate.

I've made a modification to the dialect in order for it to support limiting the FileMaker result set adding a limit handler like this:

```
public class FileMakerDialect extends Dialect {

...

    private static final LimitHandler LIMIT_HANDLER = new AbstractLimitHandler() {
        public String processSql(String sql, RowSelection selection) {
            String soff = " offset ? rows";
            String slim = " fetch first ? rows only";
            StringBuilder sb = (new StringBuilder(sql.length() + soff.length() + slim.length())).append(sql);

            if (LimitHelper.hasFirstRow(selection)) {
                sb.append(soff);
            }

            if (LimitHelper.hasMaxRows(selection)) {
                sb.append(slim);
            }

            return sb.toString();
        }

        public boolean supportsLimit() {
            return true;
        }
    };

    public LimitHandler getLimitHandler() {
        return LIMIT_HANDLER;
    }

...
}
```

The limit handler simply adds `offset ? rows fetch first ? rows only` to the end of the select query.

Now I have a test which fails when trying to get paginated results from a Spring JPA repo:

> com.filemaker.jdbc.FMSQLException: [FileMaker][FileMaker JDBC]
>   FQL0001/(1:338): There is an error in the syntax of the query.    at
>   com.filemaker.jdbc.FM_API.prepare(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.filemaker.jdbc.FM_API.prepareRS(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.filemaker.jdbc.FM_API.prepareRS(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.filemaker.jdbc1.CommonJ1Statement.(Unknown Source)  at
>   com.filemaker.jdbc2.CommonJ2Statement.(Unknown Source)  at
>   com.filemaker.jdbc3.CommonJ3Statement.(Unknown Source)  at
>   com.filemaker.jdbc3.J3PreparedStatement.(Unknown Source)    at
>   com.filemaker.jdbc3.J3Connection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.filemaker.jdbc2.CommonJ2Connection.prepareStatement(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:318)
>     at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:146)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172)
>     ... 87 more

However if I take the SQL from `com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:318)` which looks like `select * from "MarketingCategories" marketingc0_ offset ? rows fetch first ? rows only`, replace the question marks to numbers and execute it against the FileMaker database manually using the same driver, it successfully returns a paginated result set.

How do I go about this exception? I was hoping to get a clue how to debug it further. There are no sources of the fm jdbc driver nor the decompiled class has line numbers info, so I can't inspect it in a debugger.

Comment: Looks like a bug in FileMaker JDBC's parsing of the command text in `prepareStatement`. If you can create a [mcve] using vanilla JDBC then send it to FileMaker support and see what they say about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While reporting the issue [here](https://community.filemaker.com/message/797214), I've made a workaround:

```
public class FileMakerDialect extends Dialect {

...

    private static final LimitHandler LIMIT_HANDLER = new AbstractLimitHandler() {
        public String processSql(String sql, RowSelection selection) {
            String soff = String.format(" offset %d rows /*?*/", selection.getFirstRow());
            String slim = String.format(" fetch first %d rows only /*?*/", selection.getMaxRows());
            StringBuilder sb = (new StringBuilder(sql.length() + soff.length() + slim.length())).append(sql);

            if (LimitHelper.hasFirstRow(selection)) {
                sb.append(soff);
            }

            if (LimitHelper.hasMaxRows(selection)) {
                sb.append(slim);
            }

            return sb.toString();
        }

        public boolean supportsLimit() {
            return true;
        }
    };

...
}
```

It places placeholders for parameters binding in comments inserting the pagination parameters right in the limit handler.

Answer (score 0):

View my patch on the johnkeates FileMaker dialect here: https://github.com/fsans/FileMaker-Hibernate-dialect with few other improvements.